# What is "fdprocessedid" in the HTML attributes?

Tags: html, jquery, google-chrome-extension, attributes, vite

I'm working on a really small app, when I came through a attribute I never added, "`fdprocessedid`".
It was like this -

```
<button type="button" fdprocessedid="some_random_text">
   Some button
</button>
```

Now, I am concerned about what it is. Nothing comes up on google on searching this.

My main questions:

- It it safe?
- Could a browser extension or App do this?
- Should I do something about it?

In Google Chrome the attribute shows up always on some or the other element.
In Brave it shows up sometimes.

It does not appear on Microsoft Edge.

My Browser extensions are as follows (chrome) -

- [AdBlock — best ad blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)
- Google Dictionary
- React Devtools
- McAfee Web Advisor
- Wappalyzer - Technology Profiler
- WhatFont

**It doesn't appear in private/incognito mode.**

I am working alone, so nobody else has access over it.
My Project uses Vite & JQuery.

I have never had this attribute on my projects. That's why I'm concerned.

Comment: Q 1 and 3: Can't tell without more info. Q 2: Yes

Comment: See if this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75312620/3709922

Answer (score 0):

I raised the same issue here: [Why is the attribute "fdprocessedid"" in HTML appearing in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247837/why-is-the-attribute-fdprocessedid-in-html-appearing-in-the-console)

The answer someone gave me is:
"We had this same issue. It turned out to be the McAfee WebAdvisor Chrome extension that was adding "fdprocessedid" to every button, etc. Try disabling your extensions or launching the page in Incognito mode, and see if it's still there."

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I tried turning off certain extensions because it does not happen on my other account. It is McAfee. When I turn it off it does not add the attribute. I is probably to scan buttons to tell you to be careful or not, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).