# Why is the attribute "fdprocessedid"" in HTML appearing in the console?

Tags: html, attributes

I didn't find the answer yet.
I've checked my code in the chrome element inspector and my input tags got an attribute `fdprocessedid` that I didn't write and I don't understand what is doing and its function. Can someone explain? Thanks!

`<input type="number" fdprocessedid="esjjvm" />` (the value chages in each input with random letters)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Hi Rob, I know that <input> it's a self-closing tag. I do it this way because it's clearer to me. In HTML5 "/" it's optional, just a preference. Anyway, thanks for the note.

Comment: It's not optional. It's only allowed for backwards compatibility. The W3C Validator will flag it as a problem. But that's a discussion for somewhere else.

Comment: I’m talking about void self closing tags. In HTML5: Closing empty tags by a slash is optional. In XHTML: Closing empty tags by slash necessary. And yes, this is a discussion for somewhere else.

Comment: You aren't using XHTML. You need to read this from the W3C [Trailing slashes in void-element start tags do not mark the start tags as self-closing](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing)

Comment: I've read it, but it's giving an example of trailing slashes directly preceded by unquoted attribute values. Anyway, I used it here just for syntactic sugar. As you said, discussion for somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had this same issue. It turned out to be the McAfee WebAdvisor Chrome extension that was adding "fdprocessedid" to every button, etc. Try disabling your extensions or launching the page in Incognito mode, and see if it's still there.